# MySQL is VERY slow on my ext4 file system

Tags: mysql, ext4

I have a normal hardware, I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 anew. But something's completely wrong. PHPunit tests are REALLY slow.

I have no idea what's wrong. With ext3 all was normal.

Thanks.

Comment: You re-installed the entire operating system and you think the filesystem choice is the problem?  *Why* do you think this?  Could *anything* else be different?

Comment: I've never used normal hardware before, is it good?

Comment: Have you looked at `dmesg` or done some disk/smart tests to see if the disk is OK?

Comment: @Ladadadada drama much?

Comment: By normal do you mean non-virtualized?

Comment: @Ladadadada yes, it's a new system. I think so because there's no additional installations comparing to other system, except there's ext3... But I'm not 100% sure though..

Comment: @Tim the disk is a new one. I didn't run tests but everything else including MySql works fine, that is, without errors. The speed is I think slower for everything, I don't know how much slower, but MySQL is terribly slower. Maybe 5-10 times slower.

Comment: @HTTP500 - it's not virtualized, it's a regular system that works on well, regular hardware without anything in the middle like VirtualBox etc.

Comment: I thought that the HDD is damaged/bad but the seller told me that it's absolutely fine and should work perfectly with no speed issues.

Comment: What is the load and memory usage of the system?  How big is your database?  Have you tried running the queries directly against MYSQL?  What about using an `EXPLAIN` on one of the aforementioned queries?  Assuming its the file system is jumping the gun in a big way.

Comment: How would the hard drive seller know if the disk is OK now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like setting barrier=0 as a mount option will help with performance.

See MySQL [bug #46959](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46959).

Test in a Staging environment first!

Hope this helps.

Comment: just for a record - i've noticed that the bug #46959 is two or three years old, but still reproduces on the new Ubuntu.

Comment: also, found [this](http://lwn.net/Articles/283161/). "barriers are disabled by default because they have a serious impact on performance" - in my case they were ENABLED, and serious impact in my case was DISASTROUS :)