# Change partition type of a directory

Tags: linux, filesystems

**OLD POST.  IGNORE**
*If my root `/` is ext4, how do I change `/some/other/directory` to ext3?
Assuming this is possible, please explain how a directory of one type can exist in a directory of another type.*

**NEW POST**
I have a directory `/some/directory` which is partitioned using ext4.  It contains a directory `/some/directory/subdirectory` which I wish to change to ext3.

My plan to do so is to create a new partition of type ext3, more the contents of `/some/directory/subdirectory` to the new partition, and mount it to the now empty `/some/directory/subdirectory`  Is this the proper way to do so?

Comment: Please if you down vote, tell me why so I know and don't repeat it.  Thanks

Comment: If you float your mouse over the downvote arrow you'll see a pop up message. Downvotes without comments are usually justified by that.

Comment: yes the "new post" question is the correct way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A directory isn't ext3 or 4, a device (usually a partition of a drive, or something like LVM) is formatted with one of these filesystems.

Whatever device is mounted to `/` is ext4; if you want for `/some/other/directory` to be ext3, then you should format a device as ext3 and mount it there.

But this requires a separate device to do it with, which is probably not what you want.  Please clarify what you're trying to accomplish by doing this and we might be able to give you a more reasonable solution.

Comment: Thanks Shane.  I wish to have files stored in /var/lib/mysql as ext3.

Comment: @user1032531 Right, but what's that going to give you that you need?  If you want to have a different filesystem there, you'll need some free space to make a partition for it - do you have unpartitioned space available on a drive?

Comment: I've got space, but don't know if it will give me what I need, and was going to try it just to see.  Problem stems from MySQL running slow on CentOS 6x (and maybe ext4, but I less think so now).  See http://serverfault.com/questions/518747/mysql-is-running-very-slow-on-centos-6x-not-5x for history.